# How to slow down slider value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, slider

I decrease the maxFuelCount value by -1. the counter goes down as expected.but it goes very fast when I long press the pedal. how can I slowdown counter value? I tried this * Time.deltaTime / 1.5f its works, not as I expected. can anyone suggest a method or give any guidance

Many thanks for your help

```
private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (move == true)
        {
            // decreasing the float value
            maxFuelCount--;

            if (maxFuelCount > 0 && timeLeft > 0)
            {
                rb.AddForce(transform.right * engineCapacity * Time.fixedDeltaTime * turboCapacity, ForceMode2D.Force);
                //asigning the decreased value to the slider
                UIBS.NewValue = maxFuelCount * Time.deltaTime / 1.5f;

            }

          }
     }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Well you decrease 1 each frame gas is pressed. In one second with 50 fps it will almost decrease 50 which is a lot. Just lower the amount which decreases the `MaxFuelCount`. You can maybe use `MaxFuelCount -= Time.deltaTime;`

To make it even better you can use a `speed` counter which can be adjusted based on the terrain features such as if you are in mud fuel consumption speed increases like this:

`MaxFuelCount -= Time.deltaTime * speed;`

Increase or decrease the speed to an extent which you are comfortable about the speed.

Also `UIBS.NewValue = maxFuelCount * Time.deltaTime / 1.5f;` this will not work. Again with 50 fps you divide the value to almost 33 this time which will lower the value extremely fast.

Also it makes more sense to hold two variables as `MaxFuelAmount` (amount of fuel the tank can hold) and `CurrentFuelAmount`.

Then you can calculate percentage like: `CurrentFuelAmount / MaxFuelAmount * 100` and use it in your UI value.